# Webpage not fully loading with Ember

Tags: ember.js

Made a website with Ember, and deployed it to the server.
However, the page does not fully load on my desktop Chrome and Safari due to errors.

I'm getting...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . ember-1.0.0-rc.6.1.js:18872
Uncaught ReferenceError: Ember is not defined buyahome.js:3
```

It works fine on localhost.
Also works fine on mobile devices.
Also noticed that some users can load it on their desktop on either Chrome or Safari.

Tried jshint, but doesn't seem to be able to find what's wrong with it.

Does anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the javascript console with halt on errors? There may be an error preceding the loading of ember.js that isn't logging anything which is causing this error further down the line. Another error is usually what causes things not to get defined on the namespace later on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update to lastest build of ember.js? I believe that you are using a release candidate version pre 1.0. Download the current starter kit from the Ember website which will have the current stable builds of ember.js and handlebars.js and see of that fixes your error. It is strange that you can not load it from your Browser but others can. I ran into a few issues with Chrome on my Linux machine but try to upgrade and see what happens.